# Reload previous saved R files

Tags: r, r-markdown

I accidentally deleted all the codes I've wrote in R markdown. Is there a way to reload the previous saved R file? I spent 6 hours on this, and I don't know how to get the file back.

Comment: The Mac GUI provides incremental backups. I'm guessing the RStudio IDE may do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you close your editor without saving, I think there is no way to recover your script, but if you delete your .R archive accidentally from your hard drive you can use a tool for recover your archive. Recuva works most of the times.

## UPDATE

If you are using Rstudio, there is an auto-save function that saves all your workspace in one single archive. I don't know if your markdown was saved as well but is a posibility. The temporary file for each of your source documents are stored in

```
~/.rstudio-desktop/source_database/.
```

Comment: I overwrote the save...I accidentally deleted the content to test something, and saved it. So now when I open the file I have the new saved. And rhistory. shows the new saved file

Comment: I so sorry friend, definitely there is no way to recover your script because the info contained in your .R file was overwritted with new info. (In this case, a blank file). are you  writing R markdown in RStudio?